# Passport.js / Express.js Creating New Session on Every Network Request

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, passport.js

I have a working login function that properly authenticates and saves. However, express never remembers the old session, it always creates a new one for every network request.

Evidently, Passport is exceedingly sensitive to the order that express middleware is initialized. (Example: https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive). I checked my config against a number of examples and rearranged it to so if it would help, but it hasn't moved my bug. Either that isn't the issue or I just haven't found the config holy grail yet. Here's my current config:

Express Config

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '/views')));
app.set('views', config.root + '/views');
var sessionOpts = {
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379
    }),
    secret: 'keyboard',
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000
    }
}
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser('keyboard'));
app.use(session(sessionOpts));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());
require('./routes/router.js')(app, passport);
```

Passport Config

```
 passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    client.hgetall(username, function(err, reply) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!reply) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect username.'
            })
        }
        if (reply.password !== password) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect password.'
            })
        }
        return done(null, reply)
    })
}));
```

Does Passport need handholding for Redis? Redis sessions are stored in a 'sess' folder with a key like so: sess:RhodmaK2V2wDNLglV5j1B6rC. All of the tutorials I've found have been about Mongo so I'm not sure if I need to somehow include the session key when trying to look it up. Within the session entry, it's properly stored in standard cookie form for passport though: req.session.passport.user

Is there any way to see what is happening inside of passport initialize? On subsequent requests it is supposed to do this: "The general passport middleware we setup (passport.initialize) is invoked on the request, it finds the passport.user attached to the session. If is doesn't (user is not yet authenticated) it creates it like req.passport.user = {}." See 'SUBSEQUENT AUTHENTICATED REQUESTS FLOW' - http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/ I strongly suspect my problem lies at that step, so it would be nice to be able to see inside of it.

Some interesting tidbits:

- Passport has never once called deserializeUser. I assume it's never
  reached that point.
- I have checked the other StackOverflow questions about this problem,
  but none of those solutions worked for me.
- I've checked to see if the new sessions are generated by any static resources but they are not. It's only for intentional server requests. On the pages without them, no new sessions are made.
- All sessions have either a populated or empty req.session.passport property.

Comment: Could you post what your login route looks like?

Comment: Sure thing:
`app.route('/login').post(passport.authenticate('local-login'), user.loginUser)`

Currently the loginUser callback just checks the headers and sends a 200 status back. I didn't use the standard redirect options because I have an angular.js app on the front-end with routing which doesn't play nicely with redirects. According to: "WHAT IF I DON'T LIKE HOW PASSPORT.AUTHENICATE REDIRECTS THE USER..." @ http://toon.io/on-passportjs-specific-use-cases/  - I *should* be able to implement a callback solution with passport. Still, if it might fix my issue I can get it to accept redirects.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?? I'm having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your session ID might be different for every request because you have your cookie set to expire after 1 second. `cookie.maxAge` here is in ms:

```
cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000
}
```

**Edit:** I also have to nag you about storing passwords in plaintext. Don't do this ;)

Comment: That's a good catch, and may solve future problems for me (I was setting the cookie based on the Redis store, which uses seconds). Sadly, it didn't resolve my original issue though. As for plaintext passwords, bcrypt is coming. I just need to get basic sessioning working before I add another layer of complexity.

Comment: So after making the fix, `req.session.id` is still different for each request?